# Any way to remove repetition of function parameters? Function parameters as type/alias?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
class A
{
    register() {
        // Other code
        
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => this.onResponse1(msg, sender, sendResponse));
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => this.onResponse2(msg, sender, sendResponse));
    }

    onResponse1(msg: any, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender, sendResponse?: (response: any) => void) {
        // Process
    }

    onResponse2(msg: any, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender, sendResponse?: (response: any) => void) {
        // Process
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBYAWNmIQG8AoeMpVDBGNAOwBcBLA+E89+EADwAdkZ68RgxAwAZlDAIAsiADOcqAHMQAZRC1QMVgF9ipDmTDJacwSdkLlIAFysDh9lGDAAMozMbRdgBRgoEBAARpIA1r4EVip2ULQAngA08HIaWnaWiirqmqJJKZoASvJ8piAA-L5wciUpMfEAlPAAvAB88ABuyIzAja0dXT3NbZ3dANwOHDrj7Hp6xJBQCvAAgsRs5HBKHvSiPo3rhgD0h-AA8vTYovDGoBPsOHgEAHQ0DMwgTxbymR-ObtteGA+HyIORKPKpXLJVJFaomFK9NoXDyfWiwmogACMILBEJyMDxwHR8JA9Xq00cD3wH1eTGeXyivxc7k8tF2OPB0PxhOJpUR8GRclRvJSACYOYSofkicUSWSKWQ5uwTCKsRy6okuWlrrhqS86HSPhlrNktDzZaUKvAfFUMRr+SNBgcOMd4AAFPBSBQTJXkFUWsXq+CxTXS7w6x40g3vJ7GrKQgla1VWm0B2zBhpDfrdfZ3ciuj3IL1yH3EHRAA)

There are workarounds I will list below that shorten and remove a few repetitions but right now I have to repeat the function signature every time a handler function is declared (`msg: any, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender, sendResponse: (response: any) => void`). I can declare a Function type but I am not aware of anyway to declare a class function using such type without having to repeat the signature.

What is a good way to remove/generalize repeated function signature?

---

These are my attempts to shorten the above code:

- Use type alias for long type names:

  ```
  type ChrSender = chrome.runtime.MessageSender;
  type SendRes = (response: any) => void;

  class A
  {
      onResponse1(msg: any, sender: ChrSender, sendResponse?: SendRes) {
          // Process
      }

      onResponse2(msg: any, sender: ChrSender, sendResponse?: SendRes) {
          // Process
      }
  }
  ```
- Prevent repetition on the `addListener` by using destructuring:

  ```
      register() {
          // Other code
          chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...params) => this.onResponse1(...params));
          chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...params) => this.onResponse2(...params));
      }
  ```
- Use tuple type, however this **does** change the function signature and output code and IMO, worsen the performance (though usually not a huge issue for applications of this type). I wonder if something better can be achieved:

  ```
  type ChrSender = chrome.runtime.MessageSender;
  type SendRes = (response: any) => void;
  type MsgCallback = [message: any, sender: ChrSender, sendResponse?: SendRes];

  class A
  {
      register() {
          // Other code
          chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...params) => this.onResponse1(params));
          chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...params) => this.onResponse2(params));
      }

      onResponse1(params: MsgCallback) {
          const [msg, sender, sendRes] = params;
          // Process
      }

      onResponse2(params: MsgCallback) {
          const [msg, sender, sendRes] = params;
          // Process
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: `...params: MsgCallback`? You can use [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) if you need to get the parameter types from an existing callable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks I wasn't aware it was possible. It's a great improvement for my 3rd workaround as it doesn't change the function signature anymore!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Cool, `Parameters` worked for me as well. `type MessageListenerParams = Parameters<typeof chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener>;`